# Mod_rewrite dynamic to static on subdomains

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic

I used the helpful tutorial [on this site](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/6079.htm) to rewrite my dynamic url to static ones, heres my working code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/?$ /beta/user.php?u=$1 [L]

# Externally redirect client requests for old dynamic URLs to equivalent new static URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /beta/user\.php\?u=([^&]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^/beta/user\.php$ http://www.mywebsite.com/users/%1? [R=301,L]
```

and it works great, cause this url

```
www.mywebsite.com/beta/user.php?u=blabla
```

can also be read as

```
www.mywebsite.com/users/blabla
```

---

Now, wheres the problem?
So, I am working on a mobile site

```
m.mywebsite.com
```

and I want to do the same thing for the "m" subdomain containing user.php.
So that

```
m.mywebsite.com/user.php?u=blabla
```

will be rewrote into

```
m.mywebsite.com/users/blabla
```

However when I changed the .htaccess above, it didnt work.

So how do I rewrite the subdomain? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you copy the same htaccess above into the mobile site folder? I'd of thought that'd be the easiest fix? Obviously changing the website in the final line too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is minor regex issue in first rule.

Here is corrected code that should work for mobile site also:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Externally redirect client requests for old dynamic URLs to equivalent new static URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\s/+beta/user\.php\?u=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /users/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/?$ /beta/user.php?u=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```